# Python periodic boudary condition

Tags: python, boundary, pde

my task is to code a FTCS and Lax-Friedrichs scheme for PDEs. Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 90
t_max = 0.5
x_min = 0
x_max = 1
dt = 0.009
v = 0.5

dx = (x_max - x_min)/N
x = np.arange(x_min, x_max + 3*dx, dx)

u_0 = np.exp(-225*(x - 0.3)**2)
u_0[np.where((x>=0.6) & (x<=0.8))] = 1.0

u_lf = u_0.copy()
u_cs = u_0.copy()
u_na = u_0.copy()
u_nb = u_0.copy()

alpha = v*dt/(2*dx)

tc = 0

for i in range(int(t_max/dt)):
    plt.clf()

    for j in range(N+2):
        u_na[j] = (u_lf[j-1] + u_lf[j+1])/2 + alpha*(u_lf[j-1] - u_lf[j+1])
        u_nb[j] = u_cs[j] + alpha*(u_cs[j-1] - u_cs[j+1])
        
    u_lf = u_na.copy()
    u_cs = u_nb.copy()

    u_lf[0] = u_lf[-2]
    u_lf[-1] = u_lf[1]

    u_cs[0] = u_cs[-2]
    u_cs[-1] = u_cs[1]

    u_ex = np.exp(-225*(x - 0.3 - v*tc)**2)
    u_ex[np.where((x-v*tc>=0.6) & (x-v*tc<=0.8))] = 1.0

    u_ex[0] = u_ex[-2]
    u_ex[-1] = u_ex[1]

    plt.plot(x, u_ex, 'r', fillstyle='none', label="Exact solution")
    plt.plot(x, u_lf, 'o', fillstyle='none', label="Lax-Friedrichs")
    plt.plot(x, u_cs, '^', fillstyle='none', label="Central scheme")
    plt.axis((0, 1, -0.5, 1.5))
    plt.legend(loc=1)
    plt.suptitle("Time = %1.3f" % (tc+dt))
    plt.pause(0.042)
    tc += dt
```

I have problems with `u_ex` not being periodic... I want it to exit on the right and reenter on the left, just like the other two.

Would be nice if someone can help :)

Edit:

This is a picture of `u_ex` which is an Gaussian followed by a box function

[image]

Comment: I think this question could be clarified by showing example values of `u_ex` as they are and then again as what you would like them to be. Based on your description, this sounds like it can be framed purely as a numpy array operation outside of the context of your plotting commands and larger numeric simulation

Comment: @PaulH do you have some tips? how to do it?

Comment: i might, but as it stands, i still don't understand what `u_ex` _should_ look like.

Comment: @PaulH updated the question... I want this to move to the right and when it passes the right border, to come out of the left border

Comment: where is this "border"? it looks like `0 <= u_ex <= 1`

Comment: on the plot, which axis is `u_ex`? what's the other axis?

Comment: @PaulH vertical = u_ex-axis; horizontal = x-axis; left border at x=0, right border at x=1

Comment: OK so what *should* it look like? the left and right borders are already at 0 and 1

Comment: The graph should move to the right. When reaching the right border it should come out the left border. Just like an electrocardiogram

Comment: your full array of x-values maxes out at 1.02 -- I don't think you're going to be able to get that effect

Comment: I was thinking to put a modulo somewhere but I dont know where

Comment: I don't understand what that would achieve. Let me phrase my above comment another way: your x-array is set to 90 values between 0 and 1.02 at the start of your code and remains unchanged throughout all of your loops. There are not any additional values to "wrap around"

Comment: Damn... Anyway thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet, it seems that you are skipping an index.

```
u_ex[0] = u_ex[-2]
u_ex[-1] = u_ex[1]
```

The first line indicates that you are replacing the first value with the *second* to last value rather than the first.

The second line is replacing the last value with the *second* value.

You could use a few dummy variables to save the data you need to swap before overwriting.

```
last = u_ex[-1]
first = u_ex[0]
u_ex[0] = last
u_ex[-1] = first
```

Comment: still the same... but it's the same as I wrote above